# McAfee blocked web applications from sending emails - can these emails be retrieved?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, mcafee

McAfee blocked some web application from sending emails on one of our Windows Server (2008 R2). The process in question has since been white listed and is now working properly.

However, I was wondering if it was possible to retrieve what was initially sent out but blocked by McAfee?

Maybe there are still on disk somewhere on the server? Or are they lost forever? I suspect the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your McAfee policies for how emails are being handled.  That should help show what happened with it and if it can be recovered.  It might just be quarantined.

Comment: Nothing in quarantine. I'll try to dig further.